# migrating webpack to vite: Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'wat' before initialization

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vite

i'm migrating from webpack to vite, when i try yarn serve everything works normally, but when deploy or yarn preview the app just loads

```
import path from "path";
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue2";
import commonjs from "@rollup/plugin-commonjs";
import GlobalsPolyfills from "@esbuild-plugins/node-globals-polyfill";
import NodeModulesPolyfills from "@esbuild-plugins/node-modules-polyfill";

export default defineConfig({
 plugins: [
  vue(),
  commonjs(),
  GlobalsPolyfills({
   process: true,
   buffer: true,
  }),
 ],
 define: {
  global: "globalThis",
 },
 resolve: {
  alias: {
   "@": path.resolve(__dirname, "./src"),
   "vue-socials": "vue-socials/dist/vue-socials.es.js",
   stream: "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/stream",
   zlib: "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/zlib",
   util: "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/util",
  },
  extensions: [".mjs", ".js", ".ts", ".jsx", ".tsx", ".json", ".vue"],
 },
});
```